# Для чего нужен файл script.map.js в шаблоне компонента Битрикса?

Tags: битрикс, шаблоны, компоненты

В некоторых шаблонах компонентов Битрикса есть скрипты типа "script.map.js" с подобным содержимым:

```
{"version":3,"file":"script.min.js","sources":["script.js"],"names":["JCSmartFilter","ajaxURL","viewMode","params",...
```

Для чего?

Comment: `JCSmartFilter` указывает на подключение скриптов умного фильтра

Comment: Введение в Javascript Source Maps https://habr.com/ru/post/148098/ Это относится к js, а не к битриксу

Answer (score 2):

Это "карта" для минимизированного файла (js или css). В конце файла, допустим, bootstrap.js присутствует запись:

```
//# sourceMappingURL=bootstrap.min.js.map
```

Также присутствуют подобные записи и в css:

```
/*# sourceMappingURL=bootstrap.min.css.map */
```

Страница, подгружающая bootstrap.js, глядя в текст, ищет файл bootstrap.min.js.map. Но браузер не найдя его, выдает ошибку "Файл не найден".

Чтобы такую ошибку убрать, создают файл ...js.map

Гугл пишет про файлы .map, что они нужны для минимизированных скриптов:

```
Когда вы минимизируете ваши файлы JavaScript, вы генерируете исходную карту, которая 
содержит информацию о ваших исходных файлах. Когда вы запрашиваете определенную 
строку и номер столбца в сгенерированном JavaScript, вы можете выполнить поиск на 
исходной карте, которая возвращает исходное местоположение скрипта. 

When you build for production, along with minifying and combining your JavaScript 
files, you generate a source map which holds information about your original files. 
When you query a certain line and column number in your generated JavaScript you can 
do a lookup in the source map which returns the original location
```